# Adjusting distance between instanced objects in geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a collection of objects in varied sizes and have them distributed along a curve I created. The objects have inconsistent distances between them, and ultimately i would like to control the distance between these objects, making them right next to each other. Any helps is greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/XFbD3rqE1eM

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ms6CX8Gsd5A

Comment: https://youtu.be/xhmxZCiFtLs

Comment: here are some youtube tutorials to help you

Answer (score 1):

you can use this node tree:

[image]

to get this:

[image]